# Does anyone have or know where I can find a description of the Resharper Powertoys

Tags: resharper

Resharper has a bunch of powertoys, but no documentation that I can find on what they do and how to use them.  Anyone have a source of this info?

- CsUnit PowerToy-
- Cyclomatic Complexity PowerToy
- dotTrace 3.1 Integration PowerToy
- ExploreTypeInterface PowerToy
- FindText PowerToy
- GenerateDispose PowerToy
- LiveTemplatesMacro PowerToy
- MakeMethodGeneric PowerToy
- MenuItem PowerToy
- OptionsPage PowerToy
- ReflectorNavigator PowerToy
- ZenCoding PowerToy

Comment: Other than this?  http://resharperpowertoys.codeplex.com/.  Seems complete to me.  What's missing?

Comment: It's missing the description of both what the individual power toys do, and how to use them.... exactly what I asked for in my post...

Comment: The code is all there.  I'm still vague on what you don't have.

Comment: I guess I was hoping someone might know where to find documentation on what the powertoys do, rather than me having to try and follow how the code interacts with visual studio api's, which I am not familiar with either.

Comment: Jesse, I think I am on the same page as you. I found this Question while searching for the hotkeys to use the different functions. will post what Ive found as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jesse,

I'll update the docs to reflect what each one does. Most of them do pretty much what their name says. Any particular one you need more info on?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

- Cyclomatic Complexity PowerToy - if you go to ReSharper options there is an option under Code Inspection for it. Although I set to as low as possible and I dont see ANY methods identified as being over the limit.
- GenerateDispose PowerToy - Use Alt-Insert in a class and there is the option to generate the dispose method (I think its disabled automatically if class doesnt inherit/implement IDispoasble - but not sure about that)
- ExploreTypeInterface PowerToy - have cursor in a symbol, go to the ReSharper menu and "Power Toys" option and then "Type Interface" and you will get a window showing the Interface for the TYPE of that symbol ie you are on a Integer variable you will see the interface for Integer type.
- FindText PowerToy - go to the ReSharper menu and "Power Toys" option and then "Find Text..." and you will get a window to search for text.

those are the ones I've figured out so far, but only been playing this afternoon.

Comment: Where is this in Resharper 8.2 > I have the R# SDK installed as a nuget package in a sandbox sln but thats where I am stuck. I can't see any way to turn this on.